# Why is my positive and negative button text in EditTextPreference not showing up?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, preferences, edittextpreference

So I have a preference screen that has an edittextpreference. I've also set the text of the positive button and negative button of it in the XML file as follows:

```
    <EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/key_username"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:summary="@string/nothing"
    android:title="@string/username"
    android:iconSpaceReserved="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile"
    android:positiveButtonText="@string/positive_button"
    android:negativeButtonText="@string/cancel" />
```

However, what shows up when I run the app is like this

[image]

I'm not sure its because the color is white or its just not showing up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing my theme to material components in styles.xml. It does change the text, dark mode background colour and other aspects of the app though.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different color in colorAccent in style.xml